# How to create a bootable stick with a Linux distro?

Tags: usb, linux, android-x86

I used to have Debian and Android on my laptop then somehow my Debian get damaged, and now I have Android-x86 only on my laptop.

When I insert my USB stick (which contain ISOs of a few Linux distros), it asks me to format it. It's a stick formatted as ext4 partition. So, I want to somehow create a bootable USB by any method. I am badly stuck. What should I do next?

Comment: Would like to know the answer too!

Comment: @Quidam you still have grub you can boot iso from grub cmd line. search for combination of these two questions https://superuser.com/q/1237684 + https://superuser.com/q/154133